# Hubot confluence intergration

Tags: node.js, heroku, confluence, slack, hubot

I have got a hubot instance running in Heroku with the slack adapter and all is working well. But I am getting an error when trying to search confluence after installing the script.

I am able to execute the confluence help command from my slack channel and it returns with the help functions, but when I execute hubot search  it comes back with the following

Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

I believe this is a DNS error, I have checked and all my confluence details are correct as far as I am aware, I am using my credentials that I log in to confluence with so I know they are correct and I have the host set as confluence cloud address that we use to access it.

I am at a loss as to what else it could be

Comment: share your script and the uri you tried to use.

Answer (score 1):

got the same error.
I using https://github.com/lchi/hubot-super-confluence
looks like its an error from nodejs.
node -v
v0.10.42
on this it works.
but on 
node -v
v6.4.0
doesnt work.

i tried to research problem and get some test.

```
node -pe 'require("dns").lookup("ya.ru",function(){console.dir(arguments)})'     
GetAddrInfoReqWrap {
  callback: { [Function: asyncCallback] immediately: true },
  family: 0,
  hostname: 'ya.ru',
  oncomplete: [Function: onlookup] }
 { '0': null, '1': '213.180.193.3', '2': 4 }
```

so it works. and idk why it doesnt work with hubot module

Comment: Could you please log an issue against hubot-super-confluence in Github? I'm sure the current maintainer would like to take a look (I am a former maintainer). https://github.com/lchi/hubot-super-confluence/issues/new